# Check of property type in Google App Engine model

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to detect the type of a model property?

```
class MODULENAME(db.Model):
    id1 = db.StringProperty()
    id2 = db.StringProperty()
    id3 = db.StringProperty()
    property1 = db.StringProperty()
    property2 = db.StringProperty()
    createdate = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    changedate = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    isactive = db.BooleanProperty()
```

How do I test if "id3" is an int, float or a string?

I've learned so far that a model have a method called "_all_propertie" that returns a list with all the properties I've created in the model. Now I want to check for the property type so I can make the form automatically with te correct html input types and if I change the property type, the HTML will change automatically.

Does that make sense or am I too far off track?

/Michael

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class MODULENAME(db.Model):
    id1 = db.StringProperty()
    id2 = db.StringProperty()
    id3 = db.DateProperty()
    property1 = db.StringProperty()
    createdate = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    changedate = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    isactive = db.BooleanProperty()

m = MODULENAME()
plist = m.properties()
for p in plist:
    print "%s: %s" % (p, str(plist[p]))
```

Thanks, for the clues Daniel Roseman and Nick Johnson.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `_all_properties`, since that just gives you the names of the fields as a set of strings.

Instead, you can use `_properties`, which gives you a dictionary of field name to field type. Each of the field types, in turn, as a property called `data_type`, which as the name implies is the type of the data it accepts.

So:

```
id3 = ModelName._properties['id3']
data_type = id3.data_type
```

Now `data_type` contains `type <int>`.

Comment: Daniel, you're such a wizard.

That's exactly what I've been looking for.

Thanks a lot.

/Michael

Comment: @BerserkerBernhard welcome to stack overflow!  to help make the site better, here are some tips - if the answer helped you, you should upvote it.  You should probably also mark it as accepted.

Comment: Don't use either! They're internal implementation details and may change at any time. You should call `.properties()` instead, which is the public, documented interface to that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for name, property in MyModel.properties().items():
    print "Name: " + name + "; Type: " + str(property.data_type)
```

As Nick Johnson pointed out, `_properties` and `_all_properties` should not be used as they are internal and liable to change.